# Parallelizing apply function in pandas python. worked on groupby

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing

Is this possible or recommended?  I have a function that can be parallelized (its not recursive or anything), and it will take a long time if it works iteratively.

Comment: I had that issue a time ago but so far i dont know of an ready to go functionality but its possible. Maybe its a feature in the future. You can find a nice discussion about the topic here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5751